# How can I use "type ahead" in xpages for anonymous users without compromising database security?

Tags: acl, xpages, lotus-domino, anonymous-users, type-ahead

I'm developing a xpage application using an anonymous form for yet unknown (not authenticated) users. The database ACL is set to not give anonymous users access to the content (e.g. views and documents). In general no public access is allowed. However, 
is there a way to make field type ahead work for input fields using content from the database views without opening them for the public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *sessionAsSigner*-object in SSJS to access your data with a different access level.

Comment: That really points to right direction. Thanks Sven for the quick response! Will give it a try and will report back here.

Comment: Mastering XPages, Chapter 17, page 704 has all the details on sessionAsSigner and sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess. Additionally there is a very good article: "[link](http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-86M5CA) Rolling your own authentication for REST API's, part 3 - Anonymity is a warm blanket" explaining the usage in great detail.